# AWS Windows Server 2012 Ephemeral Drives... Why So Many?

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012

Here's an easy question...

so I'm spinning up a windows server 2012 instance on AWS, but I noticed the default storage device configuration uses 26 ephemeral drives...  26?

Is this normal?  If so, why so many?

I'll go with it if that's just how it is, but I want to make sure I'm doing it right :D

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't make any sense to me either. Just tried to do the same this morning.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a bug - I'm just trying to confirm it at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a bug - but a change to the Windows 2012 AMI configuration.

Previously, you could add ephemeral volumes, but it wasn't clear how many you could add.  Now, to "fix" that, they've put them *all* there to show how many you can have, and then you remove the ones you don't want.  ie - n most cases - all of them.

I'm not convinced it's a particularly good change, but that's the answer I got from support.